# Cassandra/Hector, How and to what do i set the buildpath for the thriftconverter

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector

I am trying to get started with Cassandra and Hector but i seem to be having some trouble getting it going, i have downloaded and extracted both Cassandra and Hector and linked them to a eclipse project, i have  managed to fix most of the problems but there is two i cant get rid of.

The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.apache.thrift.TException. Fix the build path then try building this project    hector      Unknown Java Problem

and

The type org.apache.thrift.TException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    ThriftSuperCfTemplate.java  /hector/core/src/main/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/service/template    line 1  Java Problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use Maven or Ivy to pull in your dependencies, then you'll only need to reference Hector in your pom.xml/ivy.xml and it will pull down all the required dependencies.  Doing this manually will be a big pain.